# nginx: try_files and external URL

Tags: nginx

I'd like to create a dynamic thumbnail generator and pass all requests through nginx and test weather the files exist using try_files.

The fallback should be an external URL, how can I achieve this?

```
 server {
         listen 80;
         server_name static.stage.domain.example;     

        location / {
            alias /home/fh/static/$1;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @bla;
        }     

        location @bla {
            proxy_set_header Host http://www.myurl.example?resize=$uri;
        }     

 }
```

**Solution**
This is what I've been looking for: (working example):

```
server {
        listen 80;    

        server_name static.example.com;    

        location / {
            root /home/example/static/uploads/thumbnail;
            try_files $uri @redirect;
        }    

        location @redirect {
           expires 30s;
            return 301 https:/example.com/thumbnail$request_uri;
        }
}
```

Comment: The documentation says it takes a URI. Have you considered just putting a URI in there? What happens when you try what you did above? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Comment: `location / {
         alias /home/fh/nginxtest/$1;
         try_files $uri $uri/ http://google.com;
     }`

results in "/usr/share/nginx/htmlhttp://google.com" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1):

URI is the resource part of a full URL, that is, a resource on the current  server. You cannot refer to an external resource in `try_files` directive.

You need to add `proxy_pass http://example.com;` in your `location @bla` configuration section to pass the request to an external service.

Comment: still getting `"/usr/share/nginx/htmlhttp://requestb.in/1h6l0vn1"` with      
 `location / {
         alias /home/fh/nginxtest/$1;
         try_files $uri proxy_pass http://requestb.in/1h6l0vn1;
     } `

Comment: I made my answer more clear. `try_files` is only for adding physical files / virtual location blocks.